# handling different MGLPointAnnotation callouts

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapbox, mapbox-ios

i have two points 1 & 2 and each point has its own callout but when i try to use the taponcallout function

`func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, tapOnCalloutFor annotation: MGLAnnotation ) {`

it is reflected on both points which end up referring me to the same method

how can i make this function differentiate between the two points??

here is my code sample

```
let point = MGLPointAnnotation()
let point1 = MGLPointAnnotation()



 func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, didFinishLoading style: MGLStyle) {

        // Create point to represent where the symbol should be placed

        point.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 26.319735961914062, longitude: 50.14814726335609)
        point1.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 26.319735961914062, longitude: 50.14414726335609)

        point.title = "big-bossman"
        point.subtitle = "very scary"

        point1.title = "smol-bossman"
        point1.subtitle = "smol scary"


        // Create a data source to hold the point data
        let shapeSource = MGLShapeSource(identifier: "marker-source", shape: point, options: nil)
        let shapeSource1 = MGLShapeSource(identifier: "marker-source1", shape: point1, options: nil)

        // Create a style layer for the symbol
        let shapeLayer = MGLSymbolStyleLayer(identifier: "marker-style", source: shapeSource)
        let shapeLayer1 = MGLSymbolStyleLayer(identifier: "marker-style1", source: shapeSource1)

        // Add the image to the style's sprite
        if let image = UIImage(named: "enemyImage") {
            style.setImage(image, forName: "home-symbol")
        }

        // Tell the layer to use the image in the sprite
        shapeLayer.iconImageName = NSExpression(forConstantValue: "home-symbol")
        shapeLayer1.iconImageName = NSExpression(forConstantValue: "home-symbol")

        // Add the source and style layer to the map
        style.addSource(shapeSource)
        style.addLayer(shapeLayer)

        style.addSource(shapeSource1)
        style.addLayer(shapeLayer1)

        mapView.selectAnnotation(point, animated: true, completionHandler: nil)
        mapView.selectAnnotation(point1, animated: true, completionHandler: nil)


    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, annotationCanShowCallout annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> Bool {
        true
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, tapOnCalloutFor annotation: MGLAnnotation ) {


            transition()

    }
```

For example what i want is that if i click on the **callout** of **point** i get to **transition**() but if i click on **point1** i get to **transition1**()

Comment: You are are given the tapped annotation in the `tapOnCalloutFor` method. Just test the `annotation` parameter against your points and take the appropriate action.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if you tried the above solution, but this accomplishes what you want. If you reference the annotation against your points within the `tapOnCalloutFor` method and then set the appropriate action, it should work fine. In the code below, I used the annotation and point titles:

```swift
       if annotation.title == point.title {
                //do something
       } else if annotation.title == point1.title {
                //do something else 
       }
```